# I am working in wcf service i created one function its working fine but i have to reduce line sizes in that function 

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008

This is my Iservice1.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WcfServiceTPO
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    dataconnect[] GetData(string level);


}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
  [DataContract] 
public class dataconnect 
{

    private string TpoChannelClassificationId;
    private string TpoChannelClassificationCode;
    private string TpoChannelClassificationShortName;
    private string TpoChannelClassificationLongName;
    private string TpoLoadDate;
    private string TpoAccountID;
    private string TpoAccountCode;
    private string TpoAccountShortName;
    private string TpoAccountLongName;
    private string TpoAccountTDLinx;
    private string TpoRegionId;
    private string TpoRegionCode;
    private string TpoRegionShortName;
    private string TpoRegionLongName;
    private string TpoRegionTDLinx;
    private string TpoStoreid;
    private string TpoStoreUnitCode;
    private string TpostoreUnitShortName;
    private string TpostoreUnitLongName;
    private string TpoStoreTDLinx;
    private string TpoCityid;
    private string TpoStoreClusterid;
    private string TpoNationalAccountFlag;
    private string TpoStoreAddress;

    [DataMember]
    public string tpoChannelClassificationId
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoChannelClassificationId;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoChannelClassificationId = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoChannelClassificationCode
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoChannelClassificationCode;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoChannelClassificationCode = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
      public string tpoChannelClassificationShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoChannelClassificationShortName;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoChannelClassificationShortName = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
      public string tpoChannelClassificationLongName
      {
          get
          {
              return TpoChannelClassificationLongName;
          }
          set
          {
              TpoChannelClassificationLongName = value;
          }
      }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoLoadDate
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoLoadDate;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoLoadDate = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoAccountID
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoAccountID;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoAccountID = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoAccountCode
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoAccountCode;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoAccountCode = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
      public string tpoAccountShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoAccountShortName;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoAccountShortName = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
      public string tpoAccountLongName
      {
          get
          {
              return TpoAccountLongName;
          }
          set
          {
              TpoAccountLongName = value;
          }
      }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoAccountTDLinx
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoAccountTDLinx;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoAccountTDLinx = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoRegionId
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoRegionId;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoRegionId = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoRegionCode
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoRegionCode;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoRegionCode = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoRegionShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoRegionShortName;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoRegionShortName = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
      public string tpoRegionLongName
      {
          get
          {
              return TpoRegionLongName;
          }
          set
          {
              TpoRegionLongName = value;
          }
      }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoRegionTDLinx
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoRegionTDLinx;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoRegionTDLinx = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoStoreid
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoStoreid;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoStoreid = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoStoreUnitCode
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoStoreUnitCode;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoStoreUnitCode = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpostoreUnitShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return TpostoreUnitShortName;
        }
        set
        {
            TpostoreUnitShortName = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
      public string tpostoreUnitLongName
      {
          get
          {
              return TpostoreUnitLongName;
          }
          set
          {
              TpostoreUnitLongName = value;
          }
      }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoStoreTDLinx
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoStoreTDLinx;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoStoreTDLinx = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoCityid
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoCityid;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoCityid = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoStoreClusterid
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoStoreClusterid;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoStoreClusterid = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoNationalAccountFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoNationalAccountFlag;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoNationalAccountFlag = value;
        }
    }
      [DataMember]
    public string tpoStoreAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return TpoStoreAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            TpoStoreAddress = value;
        }
    }

} 
}
```

This is my Service1.svc.cs page

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization;
 using System.ServiceModel;
 using System.ServiceModel.Web;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace WcfServiceTPO
 {
  public class Service1 : IService1
 {

    public dataconnect[] GetData(string strLevelName) //Giving error on this line  
    {
       var dataconnect= new List<dataconnect>();

       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString);
       con.Open();
       Service1 s = new Service1();
        if (strLevelName == "4")
        {
            TpoStore();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from STORE", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var dc = new dataconnect();
                dc.tpoStoreid = dr[0].ToString();
                dc.tpoStoreUnitCode = dr[1].ToString();
                dc.tpostoreUnitShortName = dr[2].ToString();
                dc.tpostoreUnitLongName = dr[3].ToString();
                dc.tpoStoreTDLinx = dr[4].ToString();
                dc.tpoRegionId = dr[5].ToString();
                dc.tpoCityid = dr[6].ToString();
                dc.tpoStoreClusterid = dr[7].ToString();
                dc.tpoNationalAccountFlag = dr[8].ToString();
                dc.tpoStoreAddress = dr[9].ToString();
                dc.tpoLoadDate = dr[10].ToString();

               dataconnect.Add(dc);
            }

        }
        else if (strLevelName == "3")
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from REGION", con);
            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();


            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                var dc = new dataconnect();
                dc.tpoRegionId = dr2[0].ToString();
                dc.tpoRegionCode = dr2[1].ToString();
                dc.tpoRegionShortName = dr2[2].ToString();
                dc.tpoRegionLongName = dr2[3].ToString();
                dc.tpoRegionTDLinx = dr2[4].ToString();
                dc.tpoAccountID = dr2[5].ToString();
                dc.tpoLoadDate = dr2[6].ToString();

                //dataconnect.Add(dc);
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select * from STORE where RegionId='" + dc.tpoRegionId.ToString() + "' ", con);
                SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr3.Read())
                {

                    dc.tpoStoreid = dr3[0].ToString();
                    dc.tpoStoreUnitCode = dr3[1].ToString();
                    dc.tpostoreUnitShortName = dr3[2].ToString();
                    dc.tpostoreUnitLongName = dr3[3].ToString();
                    dc.tpoStoreTDLinx = dr3[4].ToString();
                    dc.tpoRegionId = dr3[5].ToString();
                    dc.tpoCityid = dr3[6].ToString();
                    dc.tpoStoreClusterid = dr3[7].ToString();
                    dc.tpoNationalAccountFlag = dr3[8].ToString();
                    dc.tpoStoreAddress = dr3[9].ToString();
                    dc.tpoLoadDate = dr3[10].ToString();


                }
                dataconnect.Add(dc);
                dr3.Close();

            }

            dr2.Close();

        }
        else if (strLevelName == "2")
        {

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from accountmaster", con);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                var dc = new dataconnect();
                dc.tpoAccountID = dr1[0].ToString();
                dc.tpoAccountCode = dr1[1].ToString();
                dc.tpoAccountShortName = dr1[2].ToString();
                dc.tpoAccountLongName = dr1[3].ToString();
                dc.tpoAccountTDLinx = dr1[4].ToString();
                dc.tpoChannelClassificationId = dr1[5].ToString();
                dc.tpoLoadDate = dr1[6].ToString();


                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from REGION Where AccountID='" + dc.tpoAccountID.ToString() + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    dc.tpoRegionId = dr2[0].ToString();
                    dc.tpoRegionCode = dr2[1].ToString();
                    dc.tpoRegionShortName = dr2[2].ToString();
                    dc.tpoRegionLongName = dr2[3].ToString();
                    dc.tpoRegionTDLinx = dr2[4].ToString();
                    dc.tpoAccountID = dr2[5].ToString();
                    dc.tpoLoadDate = dr2[6].ToString();

                    //dataconnect.Add(dc);
                    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select * from STORE where RegionId='" + dc.tpoRegionId.ToString() + "' ", con);
                    SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr3.Read())
                    {
                        dc.tpoStoreid = dr3[0].ToString();
                        dc.tpoStoreUnitCode = dr3[1].ToString();
                        dc.tpostoreUnitShortName = dr3[2].ToString();
                        dc.tpostoreUnitLongName = dr3[3].ToString();
                        dc.tpoStoreTDLinx = dr3[4].ToString();
                        dc.tpoRegionId = dr3[5].ToString();
                        dc.tpoCityid = dr3[6].ToString();
                        dc.tpoStoreClusterid = dr3[7].ToString();
                        dc.tpoNationalAccountFlag = dr3[8].ToString();
                        dc.tpoStoreAddress = dr3[9].ToString();
                        dc.tpoLoadDate = dr3[10].ToString();
                    }
                    dr3.Close();
                }
                dataconnect.Add(dc);
                dr2.Close();
            }

            dr1.Close();

        }
        else if (strLevelName == "1")
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CHANNELCLASS", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var dc = new dataconnect();
                dc.tpoChannelClassificationId = dr[0].ToString();
                dc.tpoChannelClassificationCode= dr[1].ToString();
                dc.tpoChannelClassificationShortName = dr[2].ToString();
                dc.tpoChannelClassificationLongName = dr[3].ToString();                    
                dc.tpoLoadDate = dr[4].ToString();

                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from accountmaster where ChannelClassificationId='" + dc.tpoChannelClassificationId.ToString() + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr1.Read())
                {

                    dc.tpoAccountID = dr1[0].ToString();
                    dc.tpoAccountCode = dr1[1].ToString();
                    dc.tpoAccountShortName = dr1[2].ToString();
                    dc.tpoAccountLongName = dr1[3].ToString();
                    dc.tpoAccountTDLinx = dr1[4].ToString();
                    dc.tpoChannelClassificationId = dr1[5].ToString();
                    dc.tpoLoadDate = dr1[6].ToString();

                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from REGION Where AccountID='" + dc.tpoAccountID.ToString() + "'", con);
                    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr2.Read())
                    {
                        dc.tpoRegionId = dr2[0].ToString();
                        dc.tpoRegionCode = dr2[1].ToString();
                        dc.tpoRegionShortName = dr2[2].ToString();
                        dc.tpoRegionLongName = dr2[3].ToString();
                        dc.tpoRegionTDLinx = dr2[4].ToString();
                        dc.tpoAccountID = dr2[5].ToString();
                        dc.tpoLoadDate = dr2[6].ToString();

                        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select * from STORE where RegionId='" + dc.tpoRegionId.ToString() + "' ", con);
                        SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dr3.Read())
                        {
                            dc.tpoStoreid = dr3[0].ToString();
                            dc.tpoStoreUnitCode = dr3[1].ToString();
                            dc.tpostoreUnitShortName = dr3[2].ToString();
                            dc.tpostoreUnitLongName = dr3[3].ToString();
                            dc.tpoStoreTDLinx = dr3[4].ToString();
                            dc.tpoRegionId = dr3[5].ToString();
                            dc.tpoCityid = dr3[6].ToString();
                            dc.tpoStoreClusterid = dr3[7].ToString();
                            dc.tpoNationalAccountFlag = dr3[8].ToString();
                            dc.tpoStoreAddress = dr3[9].ToString();
                            dc.tpoLoadDate = dr3[10].ToString();
                        }
                        dr3.Close();
                    }
                    dr2.Close();
                }
                dataconnect.Add(dc);
                dr1.Close();
            }

            dr.Close();

        }
        return dataconnect.ToArray();
    }



}
}
```

i have to short this method public dataconnect[] GetData(string strLevelName)  itryed to call data from new function but its not working.. any one help me ! please

Comment: What do you mean by "i have to short this method"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's hard to know what's the problem from you description. Can you hint us with more information like error message etc?

Comment: That `GetData` method seems very ready for some refactoring...

Comment: @mdm actually the size of the code s large n many lines are repeating.so i want to minimize it

Comment: Take the sections that are repeating and put them in a new method. Why is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand your question but I suspect you are trying to return an array that is larger than that allowed by your current transport binding settings.
BOTH in your server and client you should look at increasing your readerQuotas eg:

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
              maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000"
              maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />
```

and possibly also your buffers sizes:

```
maxBufferPoolSize="10000000"
maxBufferSize="10000000"
maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should re-factor your DataContract Model

```
[DataContract]
public class Store
{
    [DataMember]
     public string TpoStoreid {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public Region {get; set;}

     //more properties..
}

[DataContract]
public class Region
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TpoRegionId {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public Account {get; set;}

    //more properties..
}

[DataContract]
public class Account {
    //.....
}
```

from Single Responsibility Principle the function should do one thing.

what your function did..

- To get Store(include related data) records from database.
- To create new object mapping each record's field.

So, you may separate **private** method to read data from DataReader

```
private Store ReadStore(SqlDataReader dr)
{
    var store = new Store();
    store.TpoStoreId = dr[0];
    //set more properties...

    return store;
}
```

about mysql query you should JOIN tables instead.try  Google about MySql JOIN table